# Stubbing File.open in rspec

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec

For some reason I am getting the following exception when running a test and I can't figure out why. All the examples I see make it seem like you don't need to provide any arguments to File.stub.open. Any help is appreciated.

```
Failure/Error: File.stub(:open).and_return (File.new)
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1..3)
```

From the rspec test:

```
File.stub(:open).and_return (File.new)
```

From the code being tested:

```
File.open(@downloaded_content_path, "wb"){|f| f.write(response.parsed_response)}
```

Comment: Note that `and_return (File.new)` is semantically different than `and_return(File.new)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`File.new` expects arguments (from the [documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/File.html#method-c-new)):

> - new(filename, mode="r" [, opt]) → file click to toggle source
> - new(filename [, mode [, perm]] [, opt]) → file
>
> Opens the file named by filename according to the given mode and
>   returns a new File object.
>
> See IO.new for a description of mode and opt.
>
> If a file is being created, permission bits may be given in perm.
>   These mode and permission bits are platform dependent; on Unix
>   systems, see open(2) and chmod(2) man pages for details.

Don't create a real file, you can create a `double` which expects `write`, or you can check out a gem to fake your file system like [`FakeFS`](https://github.com/defunkt/fakefs)

Comment: I didn't get the issue... Would you help me.. :( ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit - the OP called File.stub(:open).and_return (**File.new**), which caused the `ArgumentError`, since an empty constructor is not valid for `File`.

Comment: Ohh! I was in a zombie mode then, thus couldn't see it. You are right.

Comment: Thanks all. I was thinking the File.open was throwing the exception, and not the File new. I did this: `file = mock(File) File.stub(:open).and_return(file)`